# Existence of a vector in a given basis of a vector space with increasing coordinates

Tags: linear-algebra

Is it true that
$$
\forall\, x=(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)\in\mathbb{R}^n \,\,\, \forall\, y=(y_1,y_2,\ldots,y_n)\in\mathbb{R}^n \,\,\, \exists\, \alpha\in\mathbb{R} \,\,\, \exists\, \beta\in\mathbb{R} \,\, (|\alpha|+|\beta|>0):
$$
$$
\alpha x_1+\beta y_1 \leq \alpha x_2+\beta y_2 \leq \ldots \leq \alpha x_n+\beta y_n \, ?
$$

That is, does there exist a non-zero vector $z\in\mathbb{R}^n$ that is a linear combination of two given vectors $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and $y\in\mathbb{R}^n$, $z=\alpha x+\beta y$, such that the coordinates of the vector $z$ are increasing?

If this statement is false, is it true that
$$
\forall\, x=(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)\in\mathbb{R}^n \,\,\, \forall\, y=(y_1,y_2,\ldots,y_n)\in\mathbb{R}^n \,\,\, \exists\, \alpha\in\mathbb{R} \,\,\, \exists\, \beta\in\mathbb{R} \,\, (|\alpha|+|\beta|>0):
$$
$$
\alpha x_1+\beta y_1 \leq \alpha x_2+\beta y_2 \leq \ldots \leq \alpha x_m+\beta y_m
$$
for some $m<n$ ?

What are nontrivial $m>2$ for which the previous statement is true?

Comment: Please show your work

Comment: Certainly, $\alpha=\beta=0$.

Comment: I have edited my question. Of course, I mean $|\alpha|+|\beta|>0$.

Comment: If you now require $|\alpha| + |\beta| > 0$, then in $\Bbb R^3$ we can take $x = (1, 0, 0)$ and $y = (0, 0, 1)$.

Comment: Well, but then $z=(\alpha,0,\beta)$, and if we choose $\alpha \leq 0\leq \beta$ then your example is not a counter-example.

Comment: $x$ and $y$ are given (!) vectors.